# Images not showing up in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is supposed to be a dice game where 2 people click to roll dice and they add what they get until they reach the goal. Their score resets if they roll over 9 though. Images of dice are supposed to pop up and show what they rolled. I know the images are not on here but it still shows that there should an image there with the error symbol. I am having trouble with the second image not showing up which should come from the SetPic2 function. Any help would be appreciated. Also, the PASS buttons are supposed the pass the person's turn to the other player but the main problem is the images.

```js
//console.log("file loaded");
//var p1Button = document.getElementById("p1");
var p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2Button = document.querySelector("#p2");
var P1Pass = document.querySelector("P1Pass");
var P2Pass = document.querySelector("P2Pass");
var setButton = document.querySelector("#set");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var diceImage = document.querySelector("img");
var diceImage2 = document.querySelector("img2");
var p1Total = document.querySelector("#p1score");
var p2Total = document.querySelector("#p2score");
var targetScore = document.querySelector("#tscore");
var newScore = document.querySelector("#newtarget");
var num = 0,
  num2 = 0,
  p1val = 0,
  p2val = 0,
  target;
var playgame = true;

target = Number(targetScore.textContent); //convert the string to num

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (playgame) {
    //Math.random() --> return a value between 0 & 1
    num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    p1val = p1val + num + num2;
    p1Total.textContent = p1val;

    setButton.disabled = true;
    p1Button.disabled = true;
    p2Button.disabled = false;
    setPic(num);
    setPic2(num2);

    if (num + num2 > 9) {
      p1val = 0;
    }

    if (p1val >= target) {
      playgame = false;
      p1Total.classList.add("winner");
      stopGame();
    }
  }
});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (playgame) {
    //Math.random() --> return a value between 0 & 1
    num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    p2val = p2val + num + num2;
    p2Total.textContent = p2val;

    setButton.disabled = true;
    p1Button.disabled = false;
    p2Button.disabled = true;
    setPic(num);
    setPic2(num2);

    if (num + num2 > 9) {
      p2val = 0;
    }

    if (p2val >= target) {
      playgame = false;
      p2Total.classList.add("winner");
      stopGame();
    }
  }
});

/*P1Pass.addEventListener("click", function(){
    p1Button.disabled= true;
    p2Button.disabled = false;
});

P2Pass.addEventListener("click", function(){
    p1Button.disabled = false;
    p2Button.disabled = true;
});*/

setButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  targetScore.textContent = newScore.value;
  target = Number(targetScore.textContent);
  setButton.disabled = true;
  newScore.disabled = true;
});
resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  p1Button.disabled = false;
  p2Button.disabled = true;
  p1Total.textContent = "0";
  p2Total.textContent = "0";
  targetScore.textContent = "25";
  setButton.disabled = false;
  newScore.disabled = false;
  p1Total.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Total.classList.remove("winner");
  playgame = true;
  p1val = 0;
  p2val = 0;
  target = 25;
});

function stopGame() {
  p1Button.disabled = true;
  p2Button.disabled = true;
  setButton.disabled = true;
  newScore.disabled = true;
}

function setPic(val) {
  if (val == 1) {
    diceImage.src = "1.png";
  } else if (val == 2) {
    diceImage.src = "2.png";
  } else if (val == 3) {
    diceImage.src = "3.png";
  } else if (val == 4) {
    diceImage.src = "4.png";
  } else if (val == 5) {
    diceImage.src = "5.png";
  } else if (val == 6) {
    diceImage.src = "6.png";
  }

}

function setPic2(val2) {

  if (val2 == 1) {
    diceImage2.src = "1.png";
  } else if (val2 == 2) {
    diceImage2.src = "2.png";
  } else if (val2 == 3) {
    diceImage2.src = "3.png";
  } else if (val2 == 4) {
    diceImage2.src = "4.png";
  } else if (val2 == 5) {
    diceImage2.src = "5.png";
  } else if (val2 == 6) {
    diceImage2.src = "6.png";
  }
}
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
}

;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap
.min.css" integrity="sha384-
Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="gamestyle.css">
  <title>Dice Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <h1> <span id="p1score">0</span> vs. <span id="p2score">0</span> </h1>
    <br>
    <p>Target-Score: <span id="tscore">25</span></p>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="p1"> Player One </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="p2"> Player Two </button>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="P1Pass">PASS</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="P2Pass">PASS</button>
    <br><br> New Target: <input type="number" id="newtarget">
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="set"> Set </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="reset"> Reset </button>
    <br><br>

    <img src="">
    <img src="">

  </div>
  <script src="gamefunction.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-
J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min
.js" integrity="sha384-
Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.m
in.js" integrity="sha384-
wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First thing I notice is <img2? I would start with making both of them img tags. then giving them an id <img id="img1" src=""/> <img id="img2" src=""/>

Comment: Also I just noticed you are not closing the img tag properly.

Comment: `var diceImage2 = document.querySelector("img2");` err, that's... not right.

Comment: You wrote so much logic but you don't know there is no <img2 tag in html :p

Comment: The `setPic2` function could be replaced with a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will not finding your second image element.

```
var diceImage2 = document.querySelector("img2");
```

You could give your images IDs and reference them directly:

HTML

```
<img id="die1" src="" />
<img id="die2" src="" />
```

JS

```
var diceImage1 = document.getElementById('die1');
var diceImage2 = document.getElementById('die2');
```

Comment: Did that help or are you still having issues?